# Easiest Way to Make ASP.NET Application Location Aware?

Tags: c#, asp.net, location-aware

What is the quickest way to make my ASP.NET application location aware? I have seen some API examples that are in C++ and not able to load into an ASP.NET application. Are there other ways to go about this? I just need to be able to get a general location of my users (city level or lower). Getting a ZIP code would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea would be GeoLocate the user to his country based on his IP. At the most, It is also possible to track-down the user to his city but the accuracy is always doubtful.You can find some information on this [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location).

Answer (score 2):

[Geolocation in ASP.NET MVC made easy.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode37GeolocationGeotargetingReverseIPAddressLookupInASPNETMVCMadeEasy.aspx)

[Geolocation is easier (and cheaper) than you think](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/category/geolocation/)

[Geolocation component for ASP.NET](http://www.rolosoft.com/software/geo-ip/net/features/ip-geolocation.aspx)

Found by googling "Geolocation ASP.NET"

Answer (score 0):

Try googleing for free GEOIP databases. Here is one: [link text](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country) I've used these db's to get user's general area to determine what marketing is working for customers.

Good Luck!